# No me reconoce la data del JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

Estoy haciendo un buscador y no me muestra en pantalla los datos del JSON. Lo que quiero hacer es que filtre el dato y lo muestre por pantalla, pero solo sale 'producto no encontrado' como si estuviera vacío.

Ese es el único error que tengo, y en consola me muestra los datos como que la función los está tomando.

Archivo JS - main.js

```
const formulario = document.querySelector('#formulario'), boton = document.querySelector('#boton'), resultado = document.querySelector('#resultado')


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    fetchData();
})

const fetchData = async () => {
// esta funcion toma los datos del JSON
    try {
        const res = await fetch('api.json'),
        data = await res.json();
    //console.log(data);
    filtrar(data)

    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
   }
}

const filtrar = (data) => {
console.log(data);
resultado.innerHTML = '';
const texto = formulario.value.toLowerCase();
for (let producto in fetchData) {
    let nombre = producto.title.toLowerCase();
    if (nombre.indexOf(texto) !== -1) {
        resultado.innerHTML += `
      <li>${producto.title} - ${producto.precio}</li>
      `
    }
}
if (resultado.innerHTML === '') {
    resultado.innerHTML += `<li>Producto no encontrado...</li>`
}
};

boton.addEventListener('click', filtrar);
```

Archivo de HTML - vantas.html

```
<h1>Buscador</h1>
<input type="text" id="formulario">
<button id="boton">Agregar</button>
<ul id="resultado">

</ul>

<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Archivo JSON - api.json

```
[
 {
    "precio": 500,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Cafe"
 },
 {
    "precio": 300,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Pizza"
 }
]
```

Comment: En tu método `filtrar()` creo que deberías cambiar `let producto in fetchData` por `let producto in data`. Ya que el parámetro `data` que recibes nunca lo usas.

Comment: Si, lo intente y sigue sin funcionar. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás teniendo una pequeña confusión respecto a [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

> Async functions always return a promise.

Teniendo eso en mente, tu código debe tener unos ligeros cambios. Empezando por tu método `fetchData()`.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('data.json');
    return await res.json();
}
```

Para que, posteriormente, en tu método `filtrar()` obtengas la data recibida, utilizando [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

```
const filtrar = () => {
fetchData()
    .then(data => {
        resultado.innerHTML = '';
        const texto = formulario.value.toLowerCase();

        for (let producto of data) {
            let nombre = producto.title.toLowerCase();
            if (nombre.indexOf(texto) !== -1) {
                resultado.innerHTML += `
            <li>${producto.title} - ${producto.precio}</li>
            `
            }
        }
        if (resultado.innerHTML === '') {
            resultado.innerHTML += `<li>Producto no encontrado...</li>`
        }
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    })
};
```

Básicamente, el método `then()`:

> Takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and
> failure cases of the Promise.

En este ejemplo, sólo utilizamos un `callback` que es para el caso de éxito.

```
fetchData().then(data => {...})
```

Ya que posteriormente utilizamos `.catch()`.

Te recomiendo leer la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) para entender estos conceptos a profundidad.

Comment: No tuve en cuenta el método `then()`, hice las modificaciones y funciona perfecto. Voy a leer la documentación. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Estas teniendo varios problemas al mismo tiempo.

1: El evento `DOMContentLoaded` esta llamando a la funcion `fetchData`, luego que carga los datos se lo pasas a la function `filtrar`.

El problema esta en que estas usando `fetchData` en el for en lugar de `data`

Deberia ser

```
for (let producto in data) {
    // ....
}
```

2: tu evento `click` esta usando como handler la funcion `filtrar`. pero filter, recibe los datos como parametros, entonces cuando haces click lo que le estas pasando por parametro es el evento y no los datos. para solucionarlo has lo siguiente:

```
let data = []; // crea una variable global

const fetchData = async () => {
  // ...
}

// usa un arrow function como handler para llamar la funcion filtrar y pasarle los datos
boton.addEventListener('click', (event) => filtrar(data) );
```